# How can I get mouse capture to work in virtualbox when I move guest window to second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualbox, mouse

I'm running VirtualBox on a Win7 host.  Guest OS is Centos.  My setup is a laptop (screen 1) with a huge external monitor (screen 2).  I'm only telling Centos there is one monitor though.

When I start up VirtualBox on screen 1, the mouse capture works fine.  I don't have mouse integration because (I think) the kernel on Centos is too old to support it.  That's fine, I don't mind doing the Right-Control thing.

The problem I have is that when I drag the whole VM window over to my second monitor, the mouse capture doesn't work right anymore.  I click inside the VM and can move the VM cursor a little bit, but I can't always get to the edges of the VM screen -- before I get all the way to an edge, the cursor will escape from the VM as if I had hit right-control.  But it's still captured according to the icon, and if I then hit right-control, the guest cursor jumps to a different screen location.

My workaround: if I have the VM window mostly on screen 2, but a small corner of it still on screen 1, then the mouse capture works correctly.

Is there a setting to make this work better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run CentOS on Virtualbox, on a 64bit version of Windows 7. Guest Additions worked fine for me.  I followed some [simple instructions](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4960) to make sure the kernel-headers and kernel-dev packages were installed.  The Guest additions are [supported](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#id368659) starting with RHEL 3.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem instead of answering my question!!!  I could swear I tried those same steps a week ago and got some error message about how it couldn't compile one part of the guest additions.  Worked fine today.

Answer (score 2):

The mouse bug you described is known, but not assigned. For all who want to stay informed: [Guest mouse malfunctions in multiscreen environment](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9059)